# Around the Bend

Tags: crosswords

I saw this crossword type in a book and decided to make one. It's called an around-the-bend because each word goes... around the bend. I have both the board and the clues as a text file, but I have no idea how to put that in the question.

### Rules

- Each word goes from **left to right** on its numbered line, and then continues from **right to left** on the next line
- #20 wraps back around to #1

Example: If #1 was "depart", then #2 must start with "tra" and #20 must end with "ped". #1 would be entered as DEP in the #1 row and TRA in the #2 row, so if you read #1 left-to-right and then #2 right-to-left it spells "depart"

Fair warning that I am *terrible* at cluing crosswords. Apologies in advance for the clues. I tried to err on the side of easiness. If you all like these I'll make more, and if anyone is okay with cluing them for me I'd be happy to send over the words. I also couldn't find any good grids for this type so I made my own in Google Drawings.

[image: The board and clues for this around-the-bend crossword]

Note: after I made the images all nice, I realized that #17 has a problem. The clue is in the wrong tense! Once you get #17, add an "ed" to the end.

Happy puzzling!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that this will do the trick!

> [image: wraparound crossword]

Answers:

> 1. Darn together: REKNIT 
>  2. With prongs, as a trident: TINED 
>  3. Struck out, as in #5: DELED 
>  4. To produce a baby: DELIVER 
>  5. After the first draft: REVISION 
>  6. A bad kind of neighbour: NOISIER 
>  7. Santa needs these for his deer: REINS 
>  8. Indicated displeasure via nose: SNORTED 
>  9. Michigan’s Motown: DETROIT 
>  10. It’s minty fresh! 2 wds.: TICTAC 
>  11. What Fury lost an eye to. 2 wds.: CATCLAW 
>  12. Luxuriating when #17: WALLOWS 
>  13. Bigger than healthy: SWOLLEN 
>  14. Nervous types: NELLIES 
>  15. French river: SEILLE 
>  16. Time passed: ELAPSED 
>  17. The feeling of an impossible puzzle: DESPAIRED 
>  18. A bully: DERIDER 
>  19. To save: REDEEM 
>  20. Quite like a lamb: MEEKER

Comment: Good job! What did you think of the clue difficulty? Or the puzzle type?

Comment: Some were definitely more difficult than others but overall the difficulty was at a good level! Loved the puzzle type — nice job!

Comment: Thanks! Sounds like my strategy of Googling "crossword clue generator" was a good idea :)
 I'll probably post more of these in the future, it was fun to make.